# When my code will alert not only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#add_form" ).hide();
});


function checkID(obj) {
  var href = obj.getAttribute('href'); // get link href
  console.log(href);
  if ( $( "#add_form" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
      $("#userID").val("");
      $( "#add_form" ).slideDown(500);
      $('<div/>',{                    // create a dynamic overlay div
        id:"overlay"
        }).appendTo("body");
    } 

    $("#submitCheck").on("click", function() {
      var value = $("#userID").val();// user input
        var index = $.inArray(value, ["1234", "5678"])
        alert(index);
        closeForm();
    });
}

function closeForm() {
  $( "#add_form" ).hide();
  $('#overlay').remove();            // remove this overlay when cancel clicked.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" onclick="checkID(this); return false;">Click Here</a>
<div class="center">
      <div id="add_form">
          <input type="text" id="userID" name="userID">
          <!-- <br/> -->
          <button type="button" id="submitCheck">comfirm</button>
          <button type="button" id="submitCancel" onclick="closeForm();">Cancel</button>
      </div>  
    </div>
```

1.When I click on button, the form will pop up and I input "11" then alert -1 
back and popup window disappear.

2.I click on button *again*, type "11" and alert -1 *twice*.

Anyone know why it return -1 twice?

Comment: You are binding `click` event on `submitCheck` each time you click on link. Do it only once

Comment: Thanks for reply but I don't understand.

Comment: See below.Check the `console.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `click` event on `submitCheck` only once. To do so, take that code outside your function and inside `DOM Ready callback` like shown below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitCheck").on("click", function() {
        var value = $("#userID").val();// user input
        var index = $.inArray(value, ["1234", "5678"])
        console.log(index);
        closeForm();
    });
  $( "#add_form" ).hide();
});


function checkID(obj) {
  var href = obj.getAttribute('href'); // get link href
  console.log(href);
  if ( $( "#add_form" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
      $("#userID").val("");
      $( "#add_form" ).slideDown(500);
      $('<div/>',{                    // create a dynamic overlay div
        id:"overlay"
        }).appendTo("body");
    } 

    
}

function closeForm() {
  $( "#add_form" ).hide();
  $('#overlay').remove();            // remove this overlay when cancel clicked.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" onclick="checkID(this); return false;">Click Here</a>
<div class="center">
      <div id="add_form">
          <input type="text" id="userID" name="userID">
          <!-- <br/> -->
          <button type="button" id="submitCheck">comfirm</button>
          <button type="button" id="submitCancel" onclick="closeForm();">Cancel</button>
      </div>  
    </div>
```